# replace/remove cycle in graph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to replace cycle in the graph to a group of the vertexes (remove this cycle and put there once vertex with maximum number)

```
struct group {
    int master; // representative of cycle
};

struct vertex {
    int *to; // neighbor list

    int nb; // how many neighbor
    int p; // parent
    short v; // was visited? 0 = false, 1 = true

    struct group *cycle; // is part of cycle? NULL = no, else pointer to group
};
```

I'm running dfs on each vertex

```
void searchCycles() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_VER; i += 1)
        if (ver[i].v == 0 && ver[i].nb > 0)
            dfs(i);
}
```

dfs:

```
void dfs(int v) {
    ver[v].v = 1;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ver[v].nb; i += 1) {
        ver[ver[v].to[i]].p = v;

        if (ver[ver[v].to[i]].v == 0)
            dfs(ver[v].to[i]);
        else
                    // cycle found
            replaceCycle(ver[v].to[i]);
    }
}
```

and replace function shout print what vertexes are in cycle

```
void replaceCycle(int v) {
    struct group *g = &gr[usedGroup++];
    g->master = -1;

    printf("\nCYKL: %d ", v);

    int p = ver[v].p;

    while (p != v) {
        printf("%d(%d) ", p, v);

        p = ver[p].p;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Generally it's works, but sometimes it get a infinity loop. I tried to debug it and if there are two or more cycles, parents (p in vertex struct) are lost, it's means it works fine but there is wrong number. I'm learning C and algorithms, so I don't know a lot of it.

It's not a homework, it's a spoj problem

Answer (score 1):

Once you replace a cycle, restart your dfs.

Basically, the visited flag might be set for your first cycle, but you'd want that cleared to test your second cycle. (And third, and fourth, etc.)